# How to list 10 invoices with the highest amount along with its total in SQL

Tags: sql

I have a relationship diagram which sales has a many to many relationship with products.
The bridging table, line has the quantity of product in the invoice line.

How do I list the 10 invoices with the highest amount along with its invoice total?

[image: Relationship Diagram]

My Attempt is:

```
SELECT TOP(10) FROM
(SELECT s.InvoiceId, SUM(l.Quantity*p.UnitPrice) AS Total
FROM tbl_Line AS l
JOIN tbl_Sales AS s ON l.InvoiceId = s.InvoiceId
JOIN tbl_Products AS p ON p.ProductId = l.ProductId
GROUP BY s.InvoiceId)
ORDER BY Total DESC
```

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't a free code-writing service, you're expected to at least show some attempt in writing a solution. Please read [No attempt made](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it, it's

```
SELECT TOP(10) s.InvoiceId, SUM(l.Quantity*p.UnitPrice) AS Total
FROM tbl_Line AS l
JOIN tbl_Sales AS s ON l.InvoiceId = s.InvoiceId
JOIN tbl_Products AS p ON p.ProductId = l.ProductId
GROUP BY s.InvoiceId
ORDER BY Total DESC
```